# Write Data to parallel port

Tags: java

what's the problem with this code :
(Writes 11111111 to LPT1 data pins )
note the OUTPUT at run time is :
run:

> Port : LPT1 is detected
>
> Port identified :
> javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier@be858
>
> Port opened : LPT1
>
> Out put taken :
> java.io.FileOutputStream@1bbe9ba

and still waiting (doing nothing)

```
package javaapplication9;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.NoSuchPortException;
import javax.comm.ParallelPort;
import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
public class JavaApplication9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPortException,            IOException {
 
    ParallelIO p1=new ParallelIO();


    
}

}
 class ParallelIO {

private static OutputStream outputStream;

private static InputStream inputStream;
private static ParallelPort parallelPort;
private static CommPortIdentifier port;
static int dat=0b11111111;
public static final String PARALLEL_PORT = "LPT1";
   

public ParallelIO() {
   try {
        //detec the port
        System.out.println("Port : " + PARALLEL_PORT + " is detected");
        // get the parallel port connected to the output
        port = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(PARALLEL_PORT);
        //port identified
   
        System.out.println("Port identified : " + port);
    
// open the parallel port --
        //port(App name, timeout);
        parallelPort = (ParallelPort) port.open("0x0378", 1200);
   
        //port opened
        System.out.println("Port opened : " + parallelPort);
    
         outputStream = parallelPort.getOutputStream( );
         parallelPort.notifyOnBuffer(true);
    //get output
        System.out.println("Out put taken : " + outputStream);
        outputStream.write(dat);
        //data written
        System.out.println("Data Written : " + dat);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (NoSuchPortException nspe) {
        System.out.println("\nPrinter Port" +PARALLEL_PORT +"not found :         NoSuchPortException.\nException:\n" + nspe + "\n");
    } catch (PortInUseException piue) {
        System.out.println("\nPrinter Port " +PARALLEL_PORT +" is in use : " +     "PortInUseException.\nException:\n" + piue + "\n");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("\nPrinter Port " +PARALLEL_PORT +" failed to write : " + "IOException.\nException:\n" + ioe + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nFailed to open Printer Port " +PARALLEL_PORT +" with exception : " + e.getMessage() +   "\n");
    } finally {
        if (port != null && port.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
        parallelPort.close();
        }
    System.out.println("Closed all resources.\n");
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Does execution reach this line: `System.out.println("Data Written : " + dat);`? Based on your output, I'd guess not.

Comment: this is the problem
i cant find such message in the execution

Comment: Did you try to run the ParallelBlackBox application (distributed with the commapi package) to test that your  communication API is properly installed and configured?

Comment: It seems that your `outputStream.write(dat);` is not returning. I don't know if this will help, but try `DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream); dos.writeInt(dat);`

Comment: No! i didn't 
but good to know ,i'll try it

Comment: Port : LPT1 is detected
Port identified : javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier@be858
Port opened : LPT1

Failed to open Printer Port LPT1 with exception : **null**

Closed all resources.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

> Port identified : javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier@be858

is just a hashcode of the class CommPortIdentifier, since there is no 
override of the toString method, then you will get a non sence in here,

your write looks ok,

..and *still waiting (doing nothing)*, does this mean you are not able to write the LPT ??? or are you expecting some echo/answer??

Comment: all i want to do is to lite up**array of leds** connected directly to the port  data pins by db-25 cable nothing works
@Xoce